# Parametertune a neuralnet with Caret

Tags: r, neural-network, classification, r-caret, grid-search

I can't seem to find an example of parametertuning a neuralnet with the Caret package in R for a classification problem.

It seems like the method="neuralnet" only support regression problems.

Does anybody have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Maybe you could be more clear about what you have tried yourself and what kind of question you are asking (you could do this by giving some context).

Comment: Hey, sorry for the lack of context. Im making a R-script that reads data from a sql server. Dataframe with 200K observations and 350+ variables. Then i am using caret to make prediction models on a classification problem. Im experimenting with gbm and xgboost. Both are getting parametertuned with cross validation and the final models are being compared. XGboost is in most cases the best model. I just wanted to add a neural network to my script such that i had 3 different models to choose from. I used method="neuralnet". Eumenedies pointed out that this method only handles regression problems:)

Answer (score 0):

The list of models available in `caret` can be found [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html). Neural networks that support classification include `mxnet` and `nnet`.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation:) Lets experiment with mxnet and nnet